# Why does the Wordpress database schema not use foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Today i check the tables of the wordpress database but i can't find foreign keys to relate tables , can anybody tell me why wordpress don't have foreign keys ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress uses MyISAM, because of more functionality and better performance, but MyISAM did not support foreign keys. It was a trade off.

Comment: so how wordpress ensure the integrity of the data ?

Comment: It doesn't. :)  Well, I don't know all ins and outs of Wordpress, but I think it does so by using ORM classes which can be thoroughly (unit) tested. Those classes can validate integrity instead of the database. This allows the use of a much broader variaty of storage types. It could even use a custom file format and still use the same programmed checks. (I think.)

Answer (score 4):

Foreign keys are just constraints - they make it easier to preserve integrity of the data, but are not required to correlate the tables. Wordpress uses MySQL and MySQL can use many "engines" for storing the tables, but AFAIK only one of them (InnoDB) supports foreign keys. Wordpress probably decided not to use it for performance reasons.